# Why is MTProto so complicated?

Tags: encryption

If I were to design an end-to-end encrypted chat solution my initial naive solution would just use diffie hellman symmetric key exchange, or RSA public private keys, then encrypt the messages between the two users.  Being a traditional REST API developer, I would use some sort of REST API to pass the keys between the two users.  Then use REST API to pass the encrypted messages between the two users.  Seems straightforward to me, but maybe I am missing something.

When I look at the [MTProto 2.0 protocol description](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end) it looks way more complicated than what I described above.  For example there is padding, random bytes, and msg key.  I have worked on non-HTTP based protocols in the past, basically you start with just a TCP stream.  In those protocols you have to take care of managing the message-length or message delimiter yourself within your new protocol (versus just relying on the msg portion of the HTTP protocol, which was you rely on in a REST API).  So that might explain some of the complication, but not most.

Are there cryptographic/security concerns that is leading to MTProto looking more complicated than my naive initial design?

EDIT:  In response to a good comment, here is more details about the intended use case.  We are working on an app that has chat capabilities for its users.  The suggestion came up that the chat should have end to end encryption.  That is to say that the contents of the chat can only be viewed by the two users.  So that means that we as the service provider of said app cannot view it neither and so can't some man-in-the-middle.  The naive default approach that came to mind was for each new chat the app would generate an encryption key and exchange them using DH.  The app would store an encryption key for each chat, with the possibility of re-generating the key every so often if there is a reason to.  To exchange the keys using DH, we would use REST API. One concern might be authentication of the user you are communicating with when doing the hand shake.  I know the MTProto has an image that users can show each other to verify they are communicating with the correct person.  This might be a useful addition.

Comment: Basically the description of your approach is to do something with DH or RSA and then with REST. There are no actual details and no objective what exactly you want to achieve with your approach, what kind of threats you want to protect against and how your approach implements these protections. Lack of such detail means that your approach looks much simpler. But once you actually care about these details it will likely be more complex too. If you really want to have a discussion about your simpler approach please describe it in more detail and especially describe the kind of threats you see.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the valuable feedback.  i added more details.

Comment: The original MTProto was complicated because the designers don't know what they were doing. I assume that Telegram is still a nightmare and a joke. (Not that simplicity is evidence of correctness, either. Your proposal is under-specified and sounds like it's not really end-to-end encryption)

Comment: @JoseMartinez: With DH the app does not "create" an encryption key and exchange it using DH but the key is the end result of the DH key exchange. But with only the encryption key you are vulnerable to message replay so you need to have some kind of sequence number. You need also MAC to protect against message modification and you might need random stuff depending on the encryption algorithm you use etc. Cryptography is far from trivial. If you want to use something yourself please use established (and complex) methods like Signal and don't invent your own even if it looks secure to you.